# disable browser scrolling while modal dialog is open

Tags: jquery, css

I need to disable scrolling in browser while modal dialog is open. So I added

```
$("body").css({'overflow': 'hidden' });
```

in my function and I works but my modal dialog has big dimensions

```
width: 1260px; height: 695px;
```

so on small screens part of it is hidden so I need to add some minimun width and height to make modal dialog visible as a whole.

I tried to use :

`$("body").css({'width': '1300px', 'height': '1000px', 'overflow': 'hidden' });`

But it doesn't work and part of modal dialog is hidden as well. Is there any solution to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `jquery` + `css` solution as below:

**CSS**

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#myModal").on("show", function () {
  $("body").addClass("modal-open");
}).on("hidden", function () {
  $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
});
```

Or Just

```
$('#myModal').modal().on('show', function(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}).on('hidden', function(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**
    `$("body").css({'overflow-x': 'hidden', 'overflow-y': 'auto'});`
Also make sure that you add large `z-index` value to the modal.